# C splitting string to stringarray

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I am trying to make a metod that takes a string and an array and splits the string into array of strings using strtok(). I assume the given array has enough room and splitting is made when there is a space in array. I think this is almost correct, I just need the last push :) Here is my code atm:

```
string_to_stringarray(char* string, char** array) {

    int i = 0;
    array[i] = strtok(string, " ");

    while (array != NULL) {
        array[i++] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: The function itself is poorly designed. You should probably add a maximum size parameter, so that the array can't overflow and you should also communicate to the calling function how many tokens were found. That can be done by returning a count or by appending a `NULL` sentinel to your array, or both.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` condition makes no sense. The value of `array` doesn't change in the function, so the loop is infinite (unless `array` is `NULL` from the beginning, in which case the first assignment to `array[0]` causes undefined behavior).

It should be something like:

```
size_t split_string(char *string, char **array) {
  size_t i = 0;

  char *token = strtok(string, " ");
  while (token != NULL)
  {
    array[i++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  return i;
}
```

This returns the number of strings found, and changes the name since user code can't define functions beginning with `str`.

Comment: The while is necessary to get each of the tokens after the first one. The problem is the condition of the while, which should be array[i], not array.

Comment: @JeffAllen I didn't question the use of a loop, of course. :)

Comment: @JeffAllen That was the mistakes, thanks a lot. Sometimes you need another person to find the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the while statement

```
while (array != NULL) {
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is wrong because the array as it follows from your post is already allocated.

The function can look like

```
void string_to_stringarray( char *string, char **array ) 
{
    int i = 0;

    array[i] = strtok( string, " " );

    while ( array[i] != NULL ) array[++i] = strtok( NULL, " " );
                                   ^^^
}
```

Comment: Yeah spotted that as well. I think it is time to go sleep since I am missing the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with the shell I'm <s>essentially finished</s> building in C++, except I used a vector as a queue instead of an array. Maybe you can bounce off of my algorithm that I've already proven to work.

```
    int i = inputString.find_first_not_of(" ");
    int j = inputString.find_last_not_of(" \n\r");
    int k;
    string stringToAdd;

    while (i != -1) {
            k = i;

            while (inputString.at(k) != ' ') {

                    if (k == j) {
                            break;
                    };

                    k++;
            };

            if (k != j) {
                    k--;
            };

            stringToAdd = inputString.substr(i, k - i + 1);
            i = inputString.find_first_not_of(" ", k + 1);
            commandQueue.push_back(stringToAdd);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was obvious, I missed [i] in while loop. The correct line being

```
while (array[i] != NULL){
```

Thanks for quick answers :) Going to bed now since I am not making any progress lol

Comment: I don't think that will be very good since you also do `i++` inside the loop. My answer is, honestly, better.

Comment: Good night. When you come back to your problem tomorrow morning, you'll find that your solution now swallows the first token, because it overwrites `array[0]`. The solution @unwind proposed doesn't have that problem: It assigns to the array, increments the counter (and in a robust function would also check for overflow) just in one place.